# js weird date conversion

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I've got an application that displays physical persons personal records, including birthdate. Everything was going well, until someone pointed out the fact that the date was incorrect by one day. I started to dig a bit and found this strange behavior on JS Date object:

```
new Date('1969-10-25T00:00:00')
> Date 1969-10-24T22:00:00.000Z => off by 2h!?
new Date('1969-10-26T00:00:00')
> Date 1969-10-25T22:00:00.000Z => off by 2h!?
new Date('1969-10-27T00:00:00')
> Date 1969-10-26T23:00:00.000Z => off by 1h as expected
new Date('1969-10-28T00:00:00')
> Date 1969-10-27T23:00:00.000Z => off by 1h as expected
```

The date is correctly displayed for anyone born after 1969-10-27, and wrong by one day for anyone born before.

I'm located in France. I already took a look at the daylight issue but didn't find any relevant info.

2 questions:

- Was there anything special on this date?
- How can I fix this in a nice way? (ie: no ugly magic datetime/string fix involving regexes and witches)

---

```js
console.log(new Date('1969-10-25T00:00:00'))
console.log(new Date('1969-10-26T00:00:00')) // DST change
console.log(new Date('1969-10-27T00:00:00'))
console.log(new Date('1969-10-28T00:00:00'))
console.log("-----------------------")
console.log(new Date('2017-11-04T00:00:00'))
console.log(new Date('2017-11-05T00:00:00')) // DST change
console.log(new Date('2017-11-06T00:00:00'))
```

Comment: Hi there, have you tryied arranging the dates as Month-Day-Year while creating it?

Comment: Time changed to DST?

Comment: @Eugenio no I didn't, I expected this format to be quite standard as it avoid some dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy confusions

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the change occured on 1696/10/17 for this year

Comment: I found this https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=1969 which seems to give the date you're experiencing problems with.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca why can't I reproduce the issue with year 2017?

Comment: I guess because you're not in New York. That link was just an example. DST doesn't change on the same day worldwide. In my country, for example it changed on Oct 29 in 2017, while in NYC it changed on Nov 5.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an UTC issue, i have (in Italy) the same result as you, but this gives the desired result:

```
new Date ('1969-10-24T22:00:00.000+02:00')
```

As a side note, it's discouraged to use the dateString version of the constructor because of browser inconsistencies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Yes, but (in Italy, e.g.) GMT+2 is correct only during DST. The rest of the year we are in GMT+1.

Comment: Yes of course, it was mainly to point out where the problem lies and that using dateString is discouraged

Comment: Sure, but I'm not positive that faking the timezone is the correct way to handle DST, just that :)

Comment: As said, i'm not suggesting to fake the TZ, just pointing out where the problem lies ;-) I don't know his logic nor the rest of the program so i can't suggest a "solution"